# Hide and Show other fields with Bindings and MVVM with Xamarin

Tags: xamarin.forms, mvvm

I am trying to have something like this in the middle of my page:

[image]

The point is to swap in displaying something clicking in the first option and display something else in the second one.

but my code is not working and looks like this, doing nothing:

[image]

this is my Xaml:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" xmlns:components="clr-namespace:OneTiendita.Components"
             x:Class="OneTiendita.Pages.StoreDetailPage">
    <AbsoluteLayout HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"  VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
        <StackLayout>
            <Image Source="https://mujerejecutiva.com.mx/wp-content/uploads/2020/04/tiendita_de_la_esquina-scaled.jpg" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" HeightRequest="250" Aspect="AspectFill"/>
            <Label Text="Tiendita" FontSize="25" FontAttributes="Bold" Padding="20"/>
            <Label Text="Esta tiendita la encontre en una esquina, parece que no tiene muchos productos." FontSize="18" Padding="20,0,20,20"/>
            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" Padding="10,0,20,20">
                <Label Text="Info" FontSize="18" FontAttributes="Bold" Padding="20,0,10,20">
                    <Label.GestureRecognizers 
                        Command="{Binding InfoCommand}" />
                </Label>
                <Label Text="Opinions" FontSize="18" FontAttributes="Bold" Padding="10,0,20,20">
                    <Label.GestureRecognizers 
                        Command="{Binding OpinionCommand}" />
                </Label>
            </StackLayout>            
            <components:StoreInfo IsVisible="{Binding infoVisible}"/>
            <components:StoreOpinions IsVisible="{Binding opinionsVisible}"/>
        </StackLayout>
        <Image Source="https://cdn.onlinewebfonts.com/svg/img_521981.png"
        HeightRequest="60"
        WidthRequest="60"
        AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0.98,0.98,-1,-1"
        AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="PositionProportional"/>


    </AbsoluteLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

and this my ViewModel

```
using MvvmHelpers.Commands;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace OneTiendita.ViewModels
{
    public class StoreDetailViewModel
    {
        bool infoVisible;
        bool opinionVisible;

        public ICommand InfoCommand { get; set; }

        public ICommand OpinionCommand { get; set; }

        public StoreDetailViewModel()
        {
            infoVisible = true;
            opinionVisible = false;
            InfoCommand = new Command(InfoStore);
            OpinionCommand = new Command(OpinionStore);
        }

        private void OpinionStore(object obj)
        {
            infoVisible = false;
            opinionVisible = true;
        }

        private void InfoStore(object obj)
   

     {
            infoVisible = true;
            opinionVisible = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Any help is welcome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems with shared code.

**First** is the **GestureRecognizers** used for `Lable`(background color for testing) need to modify as follows:

```
<Label Text="Info"
        FontSize="18"
        FontAttributes="Bold"
        BackgroundColor="LightCoral"
        Padding="20,0,10,20">
    <Label.GestureRecognizers>
        <TapGestureRecognizer NumberOfTapsRequired="1"
                                Command="{Binding InfoCommand}" />
    </Label.GestureRecognizers>
</Label>
<Label Text="Opinions"
        FontSize="18"
        BackgroundColor="Beige"
        FontAttributes="Bold"
        Padding="10,0,20,20">
    <Label.GestureRecognizers>
        <TapGestureRecognizer NumberOfTapsRequired="1"
                                Command="{Binding OpinionCommand}" />
    </Label.GestureRecognizers>
</Label>
```

**Second** is the `StoreDetailViewModel` need to inherit **[INotifyPropertyChanged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/xaml-basics/data-bindings-to-mvvm)**, then when property changed the view will update.

Modify it as follows:

```
public class StoreDetailViewModel: INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    private bool infovisible = true;

    public bool infoVisible
    {
        set
        {
            if (infovisible != value)
            {
                infovisible = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("infoVisible");
            }
        }
        get
        {
            return infovisible;
        }
    }

    private bool opinionvisible = false;

    public bool opinionVisible
    {
        set
        {
            if (opinionvisible != value)
            {
                opinionvisible = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("opinionVisible");
            }
        }
        get
        {
            return opinionvisible;
        }
    }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public ICommand InfoCommand { get; set; }


    public ICommand OpinionCommand { get; set; }

    public StoreDetailViewModel()
    {
        InfoCommand = new Command(InfoStore);
        OpinionCommand = new Command(OpinionStore);
    }

    private void InfoStore(object obj)
    {
        infovisible = true;
        OnPropertyChanged("infoVisible");
        opinionvisible = false;
        OnPropertyChanged("opinionVisible");
    }

    private void OpinionStore(object obj)
    {
        infovisible = false;
        OnPropertyChanged("infoVisible");
        opinionvisible = true;
        OnPropertyChanged("opinionVisible");
    }

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

The effect:

[image]

Comment: I did exactly what you said, but it's still not working :(

Comment: @FeberCastellon You could add breakpoint in `InfoStore` and `OpinionStore` method to check whether the Tap method be invoked first.

Comment: it worked at the end, its just that I committed a silly mistake, forgot to initialize the binding in the ViewModel :v shame on me. After it your solution works perfectly, thank you very much